# After disabling offline_access and removing the app from app settings I no longer get an extended access token

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

#### ** Looks like this was a bug that Facebook has since fixed.

I disabled `offline_access` so that I could get extended access tokens without asking for the `offline_access` permission.

While testing, it seemed to work fine at first. I got a token that expired in 60 days. Then I removed the app from facebook's app settings so I could test. As soon as I removed it, I started getting tokens that expire in 2 hours.

Is this a bug? Or maybe this is a security thing like as soon as the app is removed, a flag is set not allowing extended tokens? Someone from Facebook please help me.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that this is for an iOS app and I'm using the latest Facebook iOS SDK (which has support for extending the token). After getting the user logs in, I'm calling the `extendAccessToken` method but I'm still getting back an accessToken that expires in less than 2 hours.

Comment: It's normal behavior. Without offline_access access token timeout is about 2h.

Comment: @iddqd check out this page, that should no longer be true once the `offline_access` permission is deprecated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Comment: it looks like this was a bug on Facebook's side and this is now working fine (I'm getting 60 day access tokens now even if I remove the app from app settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug that Facebook has since fixed.

Comment: I'm still getting short access tokens with the iOS SDK. Calling extendAccessTokenIfNeeded in applicationDidBecomeActive doesn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to take that 2 hour token and convert it into a 60 day one if your app needs it.

Comment: Sorry @DMCS, I forgot to mention that I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK. I've edited my question to reflect that. I'm calling the `extendAccessToken` method in the SDK which is supposed to extend my access token but I still get one that expires in less than 2 hours.

Comment: Looking further into the SDK, I see that it's calling the `auth.extendSSOAccessToken` method of the old rest api instead of `oath/accesstoken` in the graph api like on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/. I don't know if thats part of the reason but it's seems that the SDK should just work. Thoughts?

Comment: Make your own call to the url specified in the documentation so you can get it to work.  Maybe they'll update the iOS SDK in the future, who knows.

Comment: Sorry @DMCS, it didn't. I think this is a bug on Facebook's side. You do not have to convert the 2 hour token into a 60 day one for an iOS app. I'm getting 60 day tokens back at first but after removing the app from my Facebook account, I get the 2 hour ones back. Trying to convert them does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you set your app type in the Advanced Setting of your app at developers.facebook.com to "**Native/Desktop**" instead of **Web**, the `extendAccessToken` method currently returns a token that expires in around 1 day instead of just 2hrs.

I'm hoping there's a way to get a longer expiry than that, but no luck so far.

Comment: hi Steven, it looks like this was a bug on Facebook's side and has been fixed. I'm back to getting 60 day access tokens at the point of connect.

Comment: I'm still getting token that expires in less than 1 day. Does it matter whether your iOS app details are fully entered in the Facebook developer website?

And just to be sure, you are using the facebook-ios-sdk and not using offline_access? Thanks

Comment: Update: I'm now getting the token with longer expiry. Thanks.

Comment: i see its working for you but if anyone else has the same question: i do have my iOS details entered on the fb dev site and i'm using the facebook-ios-sdk and i set deprecate offline_access setting to on in the fb dev site.

Comment: Is it just me, or did they change it back to expire within 1 day?

Comment: Also-- it seems that the call to extend token doesn't actually return a different expiration time than the initial auth call does.

Comment: Managed to get 60 days after I explicitly log out and log back in again.

Comment: I get less than 2 hours and extending never works, what is going on?

Comment: My guess is to first check whether you have set up your app in Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/apps, and whether the settings in the Settings > Advanced section have been set to suitable values for you.