# Facebook iOS SDK - extend expired token

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token

I am having hard time trying to get the new extending-an-expired-token flow work.

When first-time user sign in the app over Facebook SSO, the token returned by Facebook usually expires in roughly 2 hours.

Facebook iOS SDK documentation makes the case simple. 
[extend expired token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#extend_token)

So, I called "extendAccessTokenIfNeeded" according to the documentation. However, token refresh never happens. In the iOS SDK source, there's a global int const "kTokenExtendThreshold" set to 24 (hours).

My "extendAccessTokenIfNeeded" never invokes the real extend token logic.

To do a test, I called "extendAccessToken" instead.

Facebook returns the following error on this call:

Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 101.)" UserInfo=0x87e8820 {request_args=(
        {
        key = method;
        value = "auth.extendSSOAccessToken";
    },
        {
        key = format;
        value = json;
    },
        {
        key = sdk;
        value = ios;
    },
        {
        key = "sdk_version";
        value = 2;
    }
), error_msg=Invalid API key, error_code=101}

What the hell is going on?

I really appreciate any tips and comments. Is it that I missed something?

Thanks
Bill

Comment: Hm... I guess the solution is here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9184469/303122
We should extend the access token after obtaining a short term token